# How c++ removes the whitespaces in specific characters string

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I have one .txt file to read in my work. The each string is 13 characters in length, e.g. "PM     1    ", which the "PM    1" is 8 characters with 5 whitespaces between "PM" and "1" and there are 5 whitespaces behind "1", e.g. "DPSI  26     " is 13 characters in length as well, which the "DPSI  26" is 8 characters with 2 whitespaces between "DPSI" and "26" and there are 5 whitespaces behind "26". 
Finally, I want to read this file, and remove these whitespaces between them, for exaple, all whitespaces of "PM     1    " are removed, then get "PM1", and "DPSI  26     " is become to "DPSI26" by removing these whitespaces.
**My purpose here is:
I want to read this file every 13 characters to form one string, which means I want to split the data by 13 characters by c++, then remove these whitespace in this string,  then produce 1 D vector of string.**

Here is the string name lists that I need to read:

```
PM     1     PM     2     PM     3     PM     4     PM     5     PM     6
PM     7     PM     8     PM     9     PM    10     PM    11     PM    12
PM    13     PM    14     PM    15     PM    16     PM    17     PM    18
PM    19     PM    20     PM    21     PM    22     PM    23     PM    24
PM    25     PM    26     PM    27     PM    28     PM    29     PM    30
PM    31     PM    32     PM    33     PM    34     PM    35     PM    36
PM    37     PM    38     PM    39     PM    40     PM    41     PM    42
PM    43     PM    44     PM    45     PM    46     PM    47     PM    48
PM    49     PM    50     PM    51     PM    52     PM    53     PM    54
PM    55     DPSI   1     DPSI   2     DPSI   3     DPSI   4     DPSI   5
DPSI   6     DPSI   7     DPSI   8     DPSI   9     DPSI  10     DPSI  11
DPSI  12     DPSI  13     DPSI  14     DPSI  15     DPSI  16     DPSI  17
DPSI  18     DPSI  19     DPSI  20     DPSI  21     DPSI  22     DPSI  23
DPSI  24     DPSI  25     DPSI  26     DPSI  27     DPSI  28     DPSI  29
DPSI  30     DPSI  31     DPSI  32     DPSI  33     DPSI  34     DPSI  35
DPSI  36     DPSI  37     DPSI  38     DPSI  39     DPSI  40     DPSI  41
DPSI  42     DPSI  43     DPSI  44     DPSI  45     DPSI  46     DPSI  47
DPSI  48     DPSI  49     DPSI  50     DPSI  51     DPSI  52     DPSI  53
```

My original codes:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    std::vector<string> names;

    ifstream infile;    
    infile.open("species_name");
    string line;

    while (getline(infile, line))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i += 13) 
        {
        std::string number;
        istringstream(line.substr(i, 13)) >> number;
        number.erase(std::remove(number.begin(), number.end(), " "), number.end());
        names.push_back(number);
        cout << "number: " << number <<endl;
        }

    }
    infile.close();
}
```

My expected results:

```
PM1    PM2    PM3    PM4    PM5    PM6
PM7    PM8    PM9    PM10   PM11   PM12
PM13   PM14   PM15   PM16   PM17   PM18
PM19   PM20   PM21   PM22   PM23   PM24
PM25   PM26   PM27   PM28   PM29   PM30
PM31   PM32   PM33   PM34   PM35   PM36
PM37   PM38   PM39   PM40   PM41   PM42
PM43   PM44   PM45   PM46   PM47   PM48
PM49   PM50   PM51   PM52   PM53   PM54
PM55   DPSI1  DPSI2  DPSI3  DPSI4  DPSI5
DPSI6    DPSI7    DPSI8    DPSI9    DPS10   DPSI11
DPSI12   DPSI13   DPSI14   DPSI15   DPS16   DPSI17
DPSI18   DPSI19   DPSI20   DPSI21   DPS22   DPSI23
DPSI24   DPSI25   DPSI26   DPSI27   DPS28   DPSI29
DPSI30   DPSI31   DPSI32   DPSI33   DPS34   DPSI35
DPSI36   DPSI37   DPSI38   DPSI39   DPS40   DPSI41
DPSI42   DPSI43   DPSI44   DPSI45   DPS46   DPSI47
DPSI48   DPSI49   DPSI50   DPSI51   DPS52   DPSI53
```

Comment: And what is your actual results with this code?

Comment: If your result differs from what you expect, have you tried debugging?

Comment: [regex_replace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace)`(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout),
                      infile.begin(), infile.end(), "(\w)\s*(\d)", "$1$2")`

Comment: No. In my codes, actually, it only reads the "PM" or "DPSI" part, and there are no number 1 or 26 behind them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my codes, then the problem was solved.

using namespace std;

int main()
{

```
std::vector<string> names;

ifstream infile;    
infile.open("species_name");
string line;

while (getline(infile, line))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i += 13) 
    {
    std::string number;
    number = line.substr(i, 13);
    number.erase(std::remove(number.begin(), number.end(), ' '), number.end());
    names.push_back(number);
    cout << "number: " << number <<endl;
    }

}
infile.close();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your actual results are, I can conjecture based on your code that you are not receiving the numbers (the last character of the 13 character string).

If this is the case, and you simply want to remove whitespaces from the whole line, read in the whole 14 character string and then strip the whitespace. Should your existing way of doing this work (`number.erase(std::remove(number.begin(), number.end(), " "), number.end())`), then I recommend changing your substr line.

`istringstream(line.substr(i, 13)) >> number;`

Of course this could lead to errors with variable sized strings.

**Edit:** There is no possible way you are receiving a string with all the information you want, as the issue must lie there. This is because your code for stripping whitespace is correct, and does work. Fix your substringing issues (off by x errors) and you are good to go

You can see [my example](https://onlinegdb.com/rJ9-bYiZr)

**Edit 2:** Fixed the code to be 8 characters then 5 spaces then a number. The issue definitely still lies within the substring not receiving the number

**Edit 3:** Your istringstream doesn't read in whitespace (according to comments below), so try a simple assignment operation. I still believe you need to substring for 14 characters, and here is [another example](https://onlinegdb.com/rJ0aGsnZH).

So the line you are looking for should be 
`number = line.substr(i,14)`
Alternatively, you can use the [noskipws](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/skipws/) flag to pull in whitespace, since you strip out afterward.
`istringstream(line.substr(i, 14)) >> std::noskipws >> number;`

Also you may need to update the increment of the for loop, as you are reading 14 characters not 13. This is of course assuming that right after the 1 is the start of the next sequence you want to pull out. For example, line would have to be similar to this:
`abcdefgh     1ijklmnop     2...`

Comment: I did by the changing istringstream(line.substr(i, 13)) >> number; as your suggestions, but i still only got the PM without numbers behind it.

Comment: why don't your print out `number` before stripping the whitespace and see what it contains. If it doesn't contain the number, then change the substr length (the 13) until it contains the number as well. It is probably an off-by-one error or a counting error (The whole string is more than 13 characters long).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think it is not this kind of error, because I did as your suggestions. It still does not work.

Comment: @NingyiLi

8 character string, 5 characters whitespace = 13 characters. 1 more char for the number is a 14 character string.

What is the length and output of `number` after the substr and before the whitespace stripping?

What is the length of line and the output of line? 

It is not very helpful to say "it doesnt work" without providing any information on what occurred. This is debugging, try to be robust in testing and collecting information

Comment: Alright, I use the code: istringstream(line.substr(i, 14)) >> number in my programming, then output the number by cout, but it only output the PM, PM, PM...without number, actually, what I need is  PM1, PM2, PM3...

Comment: Use cout to print the whole line now, and determine where to substring based off that.
@NingyiLi

I would take your approach in pieces, which starts with making sure the line has the information you want in it. Then determine what information you want out of that line and where it resides. You can substring the line twice and use string concatenation, you can take everything you need with junk in between and use delimiters or something similar to strip it out, etc. Then validate output.

Comment: @NingyiLi
I have edited my answer to provide an example of 13 characters and a number separated apart by 5 spaces, I see no reason why this will not work with an 8 characters if you pull in the whole string you want to remove spaces from (number + characters).

Comment: Hi, plum 0. Many thanks to you. I think the problem is in these codes: istringstream(line.substr(i, 13)) >> number; it only read these characters before the space, if there is one sapce inside the string, it will be stoped by the space. So do you know how can I change the code to realize my purpose?

Comment: you could not use an istringstream and just directly set the value of number from the result of substr. According to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/), substr returns a string.
A simple assignment operation is needed. Editing my post now to provide the line I believe you need. @NingyiLi

Comment: Yes, you are right.  The problem was solved. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression for this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("species_name");
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
        std::cout << std::regex_replace(
            line,
            std::regex("(\\w)\\s*(\\d)"),
            "$1$2") << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This regex searches for a character, some whitespaces and a digit and replaces it with the character and the digit without whitespace. The output is

```
PM1     PM2     PM3     PM4     PM5     PM6
PM7     PM8     PM9     PM10     PM11     PM12
PM13     PM14     PM15     PM16     PM17     PM18
PM19     PM20     PM21     PM22     PM23     PM24
PM25     PM26     PM27     PM28     PM29     PM30
PM31     PM32     PM33     PM34     PM35     PM36
PM37     PM38     PM39     PM40     PM41     PM42
PM43     PM44     PM45     PM46     PM47     PM48
PM49     PM50     PM51     PM52     PM53     PM54
PM55     DPSI1     DPSI2     DPSI3     DPSI4     DPSI5
DPSI6     DPSI7     DPSI8     DPSI9     DPSI10     DPSI11
DPSI12     DPSI13     DPSI14     DPSI15     DPSI16     DPSI17
DPSI18     DPSI19     DPSI20     DPSI21     DPSI22     DPSI23
DPSI24     DPSI25     DPSI26     DPSI27     DPSI28     DPSI29
DPSI30     DPSI31     DPSI32     DPSI33     DPSI34     DPSI35
DPSI36     DPSI37     DPSI38     DPSI39     DPSI40     DPSI41
DPSI42     DPSI43     DPSI44     DPSI45     DPSI46     DPSI47
DPSI48     DPSI49     DPSI50     DPSI51     DPSI52     DPSI53
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you. When I compiled your codes, there is one error: test-names.C:15:16: error: 'std::ifstream' {aka 'class std::basic_ifstream<char>'} has no member named 'begin'; did you mean 'beg'?
         infile.begin(),
                ^~~~~
                beg
test-names.C:16:20: error: 'std::ios_base::end' cannot be used as a function
         infile.end(),

Comment: @NingyiLi ok, fixed it

Comment: Great. thank you so much. But in my purpose, I need to read the file and creat one std::vector<string> names variable to include all these names. names.push_back(number);

Comment: @NingyiLi That's not part of your question.

Comment: Okay. If I want to realize this purpose, is it okay by these codes:
std::vector<string> names;
std::cout << std::regex_replace(line, std::regex("(\\w)\\s*(\\d)"), "$1$2") << '\n';
std::string number;
istringstream(line) >> number;
names.push_back(number);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something simple?

```
std::string name;
int value;
while (infile >> name >> value)
{
   // Process name & value
}
```

The input machinery will skip whitespace until a number is found (or until a string is found).  A newline is considered whitespace, so it will be ignored.

A more formal design:

```
struct Name_Value
{
    std::string name;
    int         value;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& infile, Name_Value& nv);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& infile, Name_Value& nv)
{
    infile >> nv.name;
    infile >> nv.value;
    return infile;
}
```

You input loop becomes:

```
std::vector<Name_Value> database;
Name_Value nv;
while (infile >> nv)
{
    database.push_back(nv);
}
```

I recommend simplicity when possible.

Comment: Thank you firstly. But My purpose here is: I want to read this file every 13 characters to form one string, which means I want to split the data by 13 characters by c++, then remove these whitespace in this string, then produce 1 D vector of string.

Comment: Give my solution a try.  I believe it will work.  Your data is primarily space separated, and you don't need to worry about the columns.